# Как соотнести массивы между собой?

Tags: php, массивы

Дано:

1. `$fitstArray`: ключ - ID региона, значение - наименование региона.
2. `$secondArray`: ключ - наименование региона, значение - ID дома.

Каким образом можно получить из этих двух массивов `$finalArray` (ключ - ID дома, значение - вложенный массив: наименование региона и ID региона)?

```
$firstArray = [
    10 => 'Москва',
    20 => 'Владивосток'
];

$secondArray = [
    'Москва' => [
        1,
        2
    ],
    'Владивосток' => [
        3   
    ]
];

var_dump($finalArray = [
    1 => [
        'REGION' => 'Москва',
        'ID' => 10
    ],
    2 => [
        'REGION' => 'Москва',
        'ID' => 10
    ],
    3 => [
        'REGION' => 'Владивосток',
        'ID' => 20
    ],
]);
```

Ссылка на [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/703323a1a9b8c56b8583156dfc86f204f907d5d2).

Comment: Странная структура, а если Владивосток' =>  2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[вот](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e5c5c6f36905b0c0371e0aed9a8787c9e2cda8b)

Единственное - в массиве с соотношениями регионов и домов (у вас `$secondArray`) ключами сделал ID регионов, а не их имена - идентифицировать регионы да и вообще что-либо по именам, а не по ID - не гуд.